# Can't delete pi user on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, user, process

I have made a new Raspbian installation. All good.
I wanted to delete pi user and make another user with same privileges (lets say gordon).

So first I enabled direct ssh access to user root by doing this:

```
   sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

...and editing the line

```
  #PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

to

```
   PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then I restarted and directly login as root.

So I followed https://gordonlesti.com/change-default-users-on-raspberry-pi/ recommendations.

I added a step to make new user gordon belong to the same exact groups pi belongs. So I did this to know those groups...

```
  root@raspberrypi:~# groups pi
  pi : pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio
```

... and then this to make new user belong to them.

```
  root@raspberrypi:~# usermod -a -G adm,dialout,cdrom,sudo,audio,video,plugdev,games,users,input,netdev,spi,i2c,gpio gordon
```

I also did a change in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf at line

```
    autologin-user=pi
```

that I changed to

```
    autologin-user=gordon
```

All good til I get to "Delete pi" step in the guide.

I get this error:

```
 deluser pi
 Removing user `pi' ...
 Warning: group `pi' has no more members.
 userdel: user pi is currently used by process 445
 /usr/sbin/deluser: `/usr/sbin/userdel pi' returned error code 8. Exiting.
```

So I did a

```
  ps -aux| grep 445
```

and I got

```
   pi  445  0.0  0.6  9768  5944  ?  Ss  13:28  0:00  /lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

So  I have several questions.

- How to know what is that process?
- Supposing my new user name is gordon ..... how can I make this process not run as pi anymore and run as gordon ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Are you logged in as user `pi` ?  And `su` as `root` ?  ... You probably need to log out as user `pi` before deleting user `pi` ...  BTW, if you want to login as root, all you need to do is set the password for root like this.... `sudo passwd root` and then you can login as `root`

Comment: @RubberStamp, I did logon directly as root, so I added that step to the original question. Thanks

Comment: I've never had problems deleting a user on the RPi when logged in as `root` ... If you are looking for the process name, you can us `ps -u pi` which should return all `PIDs` for that user.

Comment: @RubberStamp, I get this.


`root@raspberrypi:~# ps -u pi
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  477 ?        00:00:00 systemd
  484 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
  494 tty1     00:00:00 bash`

Comment: See this [Unix Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213334/why-add-parentheses-around-a-process-name)

Comment: @RubberStamp, no clue on that. Maybe I am not that sharp on it.

Comment: The (sd-sam) process is a fork of PID 1.  It's a normal process associated with logged in users on a `systemd` init machine... which includes Raspbian.  Sometimes a process started by a logged in user will hang the `sd-pam` close.  So, it's likely that somehow something was setup to autologin the user `pi` or some sort of `chroot` option somewhere.  If this is a new installation, it should be safe just to `kill` the process and delete the user...  Your OS seems to be listed as Raspbian...  is it `jessie` or `stretch`? The official image or `noobs` ?

Comment: Use pw or usermod. Or vipw. Delete the pi user. Fix any ensuinf errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I tracked it down for you...

You removed the `lightdm autologin` for user `pi` ... but, if you are using `noobs`, there is another `autologin` here:

```
/etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service

line 28:

ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I $TERM
```

So, it seems that `noobs` is has two locations for `autologin` with the user `pi`

Remove the second one, and see what happens.

Comment: How to remove "the second one"? `sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service`?

Answer (score 5):

I did what [rubberstamp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75288) did, but it still did noy work.

So I went to preferences, raspberry pi configuration and removed the check from auto login. Then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rename both files and terminal autologins will not occur on the next reboot. A reboot is required or autologin will continue to relogin anytime these terminals exits.

`sudo mv /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service.bak`

`sudo mv /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf.bak`

For lightdm, I comment out the autologin line with:

`sudo sed -i.bak 's/^autologin-user=pi/#autologin-user=pi/g;' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`