# Can not delete process on Raspbian in order to remove default user

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, noobs

I'm trying to delete default `pi` user, i've tried many things but it seems that i can't have him removed.

This is what i do

delete processes of `pi` user

```
sudo pkill -u pi
```

delete user

```bsh
sudo deluser pi
```

retuns

```
Removing user pi ...
Warning: group pi has no more members.
userdel: user pi is currently used by process 1730
```

even if i kill that process and rerun the commands there is another process that get's activated on another `PID`

`ps -lp {process id}`

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S  1000   657     1  0  80   0 -  3676 -      ?        00:00:00 systemd
```

I'm following [this documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/security.md) to enhance security on my raspberry

Related stack overflow post that didn't work for me:
[Can't delete pi user on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75272/cant-delete-pi-user-on-raspbian)

Comment: Welcome -- but it would be useful if you could say *what* process that is.  Eg., edit in the output from `ps -lp ___` replacing `___` with the pid.

Comment: it's `systemd` i'll update the question with it

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?  If that starts up again at boot, it is because pi is being autologged in, as per that other question, and you have to disable that.  If it doesn't you should be free to delete pi.

Comment: I'm already signed in  with my new user and `ls /home` shows only my new user. How is the pi logged in? . On `reboot` says `User pi is logged in on tty1`, of course i'm forcing it with `systemctl reboot -i`

Comment: i tried `sudo pkill -KILL -u pi` and still doesn't kill the processes, there are replaced with new ones

Comment: *"How is the pi logged in?"* -> Because autologin is enabled.  That's the only way that can happen.  So the problem is the same problem as from the post who's solution "didn't work for you".  Unfortunately it is impossible to say what you did wrong, what might have changed in the past few years etc. since you don't actually explain what you did and what "didn't work".